# Unable to add plugin to cordova 3.0 for Ios application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have added application preference plugin to my cordova project which i have created with version 3.0.

I have added the applicationpreferences.h and .m files(after downloading the plugin from github) to the Plugins directory and then i have added its js files to the script folder and have given the reference in index.html page too.

But i am not able to get any preference in settings when i run the application.
On researching i found out that i need to edit the config.xml file and to register the plugin.

I need to add a feature like

```
<feature name="ApplicationPreferences">
  <param name="ios-package" value="applicationPreferences"/>
</feature>
```

i have done this step also but then also i am not getting any settings added in my simulator.

I think that there is some errors in the way i am giving value to the param.

Please help me with that.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `<feature>` tag in config.xml is what Cordova interrogates to set up installed plugins and map them between the JavaScript cordova call and the native interface(s)/class(es).

So it is decoded as follows:

```
<feature name="myPluginNameKey">
    <param name="ios-package" value="applicationPreferences"/>
</feature>
```

- feature `name` references the Cordova module that the JavaScript module calls (via cordova.exec(...)). So, in this instance: `cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'myPluginNameKey', 'nativeMethodCall', [parameters])`
- param `name` - always ios-package if it's for iOS.
- `value` is the Objective-C interface that's called in the native code - so presumably you have an interface called `@applicationPreferences` in your objective-C code?
- `nativeMethodCall` is the method in your native interface that you want to map to that JavaScript call.